# How to write byte[] to an IoSession

Tags: java, mina

As shown below I can read the byte[]  sent from an IoSession without having a protocol decoder.

```
IoBuffer in = (IoBuffer) message;
byte[] inBytes = in.array();
int length = inBytes[0];
inBytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(inBytes, 1, length + 1);
ByteString incomingMessage = ByteString.copyFrom(inBytes);
```

But when I try to do:

```
someIoSession.write(incomingMessage.toByteArray());
```

I get the following error.

`Don't know how to handle message of type XXXX.  Are you missing a protocol encoder?`

How can I just write the bytes into an IoSession?

Answer (score 1):

```
someIoSession.write(IoBuffer.wrap(incomingMessage.toByteArray()));
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, one should always add an explanation to it.